# Google Maps Engine API guide?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-app-engine

I am trying to build an Android app that stores my users' locations online and shares it with everyone using my app. I have managed to piece together the following code:

```
 package com.example.test;

 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);
     Location l = null;
     for (int i = providers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
     {
         l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
         if (l != null)
             break;
     }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(),l.getLongitude());
    float heading = l.getBearing();
    float speed = l.getSpeed();     
    EditText et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
    et.setText(heading + " " + speed);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapCenter, 13));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .position(mapCenter)
            .flat(true)
            .rotation(245));
    }
 }
```

This works up to here, it gets my current location, bearing, speed, and plots me on a map on my Android phone.
Now I need to send this data somewhere, and get the other users from there... 
I've been reading all over the net on how to do this, but I am not coming up with any step by step examples.... :(
I have read almost everything on:
Google Datastore Api
Google Cloud Store Api
Google Maps Engine Api

All three should be able to do this in some form or other, but I just don't have enough pieces of code to put it all together.

I'd rather not have to do HTTP and just do it with Java as part of my above code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be any sort of solution that doesn't involve a server and thus HTTP. Even if you were sending directly between 2 phones, you'd need a server intermediary. Likely you want to be updating a database online (sending HTTP POSTs with an AsyncTask) and then requesting locations from the server (either with a service that polls it occasionally or setting up a websocket - no good guides yet for the latter). Another reason that you'd want the server in between anyway is to take care of authentication, so no one can reverse engineer a way to request or intercept location data about a user they shouldn't have access to.

Comment: ok http... how? I've been reading up and down Google Datastore help pages and can't seem to stick them together...